# Getting the Base URL of the application inside of the ASP.NET Core HostedService

Tags: asp.net-core

I need to obtain the base URL of the ASP.NET Core application inside of one of  the HostedServices.

I need this because it does a request to the same ASP.NET core application in which it is hosted (the purpose is warming up, to improve the first call performance to the User).

For now my solution is to keep the base URL in the config file or just in the hosted service private variable.

https://github.com/BBGONE/JRIApp.Core/blob/master/DEMOS/RIAppDemoMVC/RIAppDemo/Utils/WarmUpService.cs

But i think, there's a way to obtain it from the startup code, but i don't know where it is hidden.

Anybody know how it can be obtained?

P.S. - there are solutions to obtain it from the request information, but  the HostedService is started before any request have been done. So it's not suitable in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found how to obtain the address of the appllication.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
{
    var addresses = application.ServerFeatures.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>().Addresses;
}
```

Although it has an issue https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/811 and can not be used if the application is hosted in the IIS or IIS Express.

They say:

> That's not going to work for IIS or IIS Express. IIS is running as a
>   reverse proxy. It picks a random port for your process to listen on
>   and does not flow the public address information to you. The only way
>   to get the public address information is from incoming requests.

The ASP.NET Core Module generates a dynamic port to assign to the backend process. CreateDefaultBuilder calls the UseIISIntegration method. UseIISIntegration configures Kestrel to listen on the dynamic port at the localhost IP address (127.0.0.1). If the dynamic port is 1234, Kestrel listens at 127.0.0.1:1234. This configuration replaces other URL configurations provided by.

But if you get the feature from the WebHost after it was built, then this can be used to get the local address for warm up.

I tried this way:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
            var builder = CreateWebHostBuilder(args);
            var webHost = builder.Build();
            var addresses = webHost.ServerFeatures.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>().Addresses;
            var address = addresses.FirstOrDefault();
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("BaseUrl", address?? "");
            webHost.Run();
  }
```

and got the local Kestrel address in the WarmUpService like this:

```
string baseUrl = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("BaseUrl").ToString();
```

Comment: By the way, I stopped to use this feature because if you use IIS integration, you can not use this address anyway. The middleware checks that the request must contain a token which IIS generates and provides with each request to the service. You own requests are rejected by the middleware.